# Insert php date("Y-m-d") directly into SQL query

Tags: php, sql, date

I am currently running an SQL query to count results from yesterday.  I am trying to compact my code down and am wondering if there is a way I can insert the following command...

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
```

directly into my query?  Currently I am assigning it a variable and then inserting the variable like this...

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE value='d01' AND date LIKE '%$yesterday%'
```

Comment: Are you using PDO? if so, why don't you just bind it as a parameter?

Comment: date like '%$yesterday%'?  If you are storing dates as strings compacting your code is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql function to do the JOB as

```
date = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Here further explanation

```
mysql> select DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+---------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) |
+---------------------------------+
| 2014-04-20 07:27:01             | 
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
+---------------------------------------+
| DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2014-04-20                            | 
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Interval 1 day does not mean "Yesterday".

Comment: Yes its yesterday check that in mysql first and see how the result comes. You can eliminate the H:i:s using the DATE()

Comment: Better now - but i think, when the date is saved with H:i:s, youll need `DATE(date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with plain (my)SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE value='d01' AND
   YEAR(date) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
   MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
   DAY(date) = DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

or - to keep it compact:

```
  WHERE DATE(date_column) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

It is important to not just use the interval, because it will go back 24 hours - so at 23:50 you'll only catch 10 Minutes of "Yesterday". Either compare just year/month and day - or use the `DATE()` function on both sides which will reduce both sides to exactly that: year/month and day.

Comment: In an effort to compact my code though would this just not add more bloat?

Comment: @fightstarr20 See my comment on the other post: You can reduce it to `DATE(date_column) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE value='d01' AND DATE(date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: this will return "all" rows, cause you not comparing your date to anything.

Comment: Still wrong, cause `Interval 1 day` does not mean "Yesterday".

Comment: than what does it mean?

Comment: First, you are comparing with `=` - meaning, when `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY` will return 2014-04-21 15:00:00 - you will search EXACTLY for ONE entry at 2014-04-20 15:00:00. So you need to use `>=`. Then, the interval means, it will ONLY pick up values not older than 24 hours - but at 15:00 it will miss 15 hours "of yesterday".

Comment: now it's correct. However now it's the third answer providing the same statement :)